# When are teams allowed to play in the LCS or Challenger Series

Tags: league-of-legends, competitive-gaming

1. How do teams qualify to play in the Challenger Series?
2. How do teams qualify to play in the LCS?
3. Are there major differences between EUW and NA?
4. Are there restrictions to the members nationalities?

Comment: please leave a comment with the downvote, so I get the chance to improve my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. How do teams qualify to play in the Challenger Series?**

Well this is a little bit difficult for me to explain but, [here](http://na.lolesports.com/articles/introducing-2014-challenger-series) you have the official page.

**2. How do teams qualify to play in the LCS?**

> At the end of the season, the top seven teams will automatically
>   re-qualify for the LCS. The 8th and 9th place LCS teams will then play
>   in a Promotion Tournament against the 2nd and 3rd place Challenger
>   Series (CS) teams to retain their spot in the LCS. The 8th place LCS
>   team will get their choice of CS opponent. The 10th place LCS team
>   will automatically be relegated to the Challenger Series, while the
>   1st place Challenger team will automatically qualify for the LCS. You
>   can find more information on the 2015 LCS changes [here.](http://euw.lolesports.com/articles/championship-points-unlocked-and-more-2015-lcs-changes)

EDIT: Rules have changed since now:

**For NALCS:**

LCS Teams 1 through 8 auto-requalify team 9 and 10 go into a relegation, double elemination tournament against Challenger 1-2.

Seeding for first round is NALCS 9 vs Chall. 2 and NALCS 10 vs Chall. 1

**For EU LCS**

Teams 1 through 4 of each group auto requalify, team 5 goes to relegation.

Both finalists of the Challenger series go to the double elimination relegation tournament.

The Relegated team from the EULCS with the best record decides who, from the 2 teams from challenger they want in 1st round. The relegated team with the worst record gets the other challenger finalist.

**3. Are there major differences between EUW and NA?**

The rules and the way to qualify for each region are the same.

**4. Are there restrictions to the members nationalities?**

I think that the unique restriction is about the gaming brand, they change it last year, because of Samsung White and Samsung Blue. And now its company or brand can only have one team in the LCS or challenger series.

Comment: if you add how to qualify for the CS. this answer will be perfect

Comment: Well I think that it appears on the page I linked, am I wrong?

Comment: you're right! I read the link to late

Comment: Isn't there a unique restriction to where a player declares nationality? 
There are only 2 members allowed from different regions into your native region's team.  The main reason you can't bring an entire roster over to play in a new region.